# Why my TodoList's Todos field is not fill when I add a Todo?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, asp.net-core

For a student project I have to build a .NET-Core 2.1 Todo API.

My Todo entity :

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace TodoApi.Entities
{
    public class Todo
    {
        public int TodoId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsComplete { get; set; }        
        public int TodoListId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My ListTodo entity :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TodoApi.Entities
{
    public class TodoList
    {
        public int TodoListId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Todo> Todos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My TodoController :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using TodoApi.Context;
using TodoApi.Entities;
namespace TodoApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TodoController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly TodoContext _context;

        public TodoController(TodoContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Todo item)
        {
            var todoList = _context.TodoList.Find(item.TodoListId);
            _context.Todo.Add(item);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            todoList.Todos.Add(item);
            _context.TodoList.Update(todoList);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return CreatedAtRoute("GetTodo", new { id = item.TodoId }, item);
        }
}
```

My ListTodoController :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using TodoApi.Context;
using TodoApi.Entities;

namespace TodoApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TodoListController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly TodoContext _context;

        public TodoListController(TodoContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<List<TodoList>> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.TodoList.ToList();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetTodoList")]
        public ActionResult<TodoList> GetById(int id)
        {
            var item = _context.TodoList.Find(id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return item;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(TodoList item)
        {
            var todos = new List<Todo>();

            item.Todos = todos;

            _context.TodoList.Add(item);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("GetTodo", new { id = item.TodoListId }, item);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally my TodoContext :

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TodoApi.Entities;

namespace TodoApi.Context
{
    public class TodoContext : DbContext
    {
        public TodoContext(DbContextOptions<TodoContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Todo> Todo { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TodoList> TodoList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Ok now I will explain the issue :

1. I build the app -> all is ok no error, my api is reachable trough postman
2. I post a new clean TodoList on POST TodoList endpoint

Request body json Payload :

```
{
    "name": "TodoList Name",
    "isComplete": false,
}
```

Body Api response :

```
{
    "todoListId": 1,
    "name": "TodoList Name",
    "todos": []
}
```

3. I post a new Todo with the previous todoListId : 1 on Todo endpoint

Request body json Payload :

```
{
    "name": "Todo Name",
    "isComplete": false,
    "todoListId": 1
}
```

Body Api response :

```
{
    "todoId": 1,
    "name": "Todo Name",
    "isComplete": false,
    "todoListId": 1
}
```

3. Finally my problem ... Now i try to get my TodoList on GET/id TodoList endpoint

Body Api response :

```
{
    "todoListId": 1,
    "name": "TodoList Name",
    "todos": null
}
```

**I don't understand what I m doing wrong, why the "todos" field value is now null ?**

Comment: See [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data). Your `TodoList.Todos` property is the *navigation property* here.

Comment: `_context.TodoList.Include(x => Todos).Find(id);`

Answer (score 0):

Thank to @Kirk Larkin and @Hubert Jarema :

Correct code for my ListTodo Controller GET/id endpoint :

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetTodoList")]
public ActionResult<TodoList> GetById(int id)
{
    var item = _context.TodoList.Find(id);
    _context.TodoList.Include(x => x.Todos).ToList();
    if (item == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return item;
}
```

Comment: That's not quite right - that second line is loading *all* the `TodoList` entities into memory. You should remove that second line and just make the first one `var item = _context.TodoList.Include(x => x.Todos).Find(id);` in order to load only the one entity and fill in its `Todos` navigation property.